# How to format CMFCPropertyGridProperty for float/double values

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have several properties that are floats. By default, the CMFCPropertyGridProperty displays these with 6 decimal places. I want them to display with 2 decimal places as in `12.75` vs `12.750000`. So I put in the following line:

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty::m_strFormatFloat = "%.2f";
```

That makes it display correctly with 2 decimal places. But when I change the value, `%.2f` is not a valid scanf format, so the program blows up.

I tried overriding the `FormatProperty()` function like this:

```
class PropertyGrid2Digits : public CMFCPropertyGridProperty
{
public:
    PropertyGrid2Digits(const CString& strName, const float InitialValue = 0, LPCTSTR lpszDescr = NULL, DWORD_PTR dwData = 0);
    virtual ~PropertyGrid2Digits();
    virtual CString FormatProperty() {
        CString str;
        str.Format("%.2f", GetValue().fltVal);
        return str;
    }
};
```

but my version only gets called when the property is first created. Somehow, the `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::FormatProperty()` function gets called whenever the property gets painted.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing "the CMFCPropertyGridProperty::FormatProperty() function gets called whenever the property gets painted" -- so what exactly is the problem with `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::FormatProperty()`?

Comment: The base `FormatProperty()` function gets called, not my override.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why that can happen is not all property items have been created with `new PropertyGrid2Digits(...)`